# How to get second text of p tag of article tag which have same class?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, google-colaboratory

I am using beautifulsoup to scrape data from website.

I want to fetch title and abstract from the pages and store it.
I am able to fetch the title however I am facing issue in extracting abstract because the abstract has the same css class as the article tag of title.

Website:http://www.globalbigdataconference.com/santa-clara/global-artificial-intelligence-virtual-conference-125/speaker-details/aaron-burciaga-114059.html

What I have tried so far:

```
tempURL = 'http://www.globalbigdataconference.com/santa-clara/global-artificial-intelligence-virtual-conference-125/speaker-details/aaron-burciaga-114059.html'

page = requests.get(tempURL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
Tag = soup.find_all('h4', class_ = 'clearfix Roboto-Medium font13 sbl-t t-b-m0')
Value = soup.find_all('h4', class_ = 'clearfix Roboto-Medium font15 sbl-t t-b-m0 dks-t l-h20')
topic = soup.find( 'article', class_ = 'clearfix font14 dkg-t Roboto-Regular t-p15 l-h26')
#print('Topic:' + topic.text)
abstract = soup.select('article > p')[2].get_text()
print(abstract)
```

The issue I am facing here is that ('article > p')[2] goes on to read the complete page I want it to just read the abstract

.

Comment: There's a far simpler way to approach this if you can use lxml instead of beautifulsoup.

Comment: Simply make use of split() on new lines?
abstract = soup.select('article > p')[2].get_text().split('\n')[1]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.contents` to get the text you need.

> A tag’s children are available in a list called `.contents` - [Docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children)

Here is how to do it.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.globalbigdataconference.com/santa-clara/global-artificial-intelligence-virtual-conference-125/speaker-details/aaron-burciaga-114059.html'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
p = soup.find_all('article', class_='clearfix font14 dkg-t Roboto-Regular t-p15 l-h26')[1]
abstract = p.find('p').contents[0]
print(abstract)
```

```
During this session, Aaron Burciaga CAP, will review the methods, critical components, emerging technology and innovative methods for designing and building artificial intelligence and maching learning systems that are “made to stick” by driving adoption and adherence principles as much with the users as with the engineers. Having developed Analytics Centers of Excellence for Fortune 100 Companies, growing and leading teams of over 400 data scientists, and being key advisor to government officials on the establishment of AI programs, Aaron will share how to deliver more “Practical AI”.
```